# Grouping the columns and identifying values which are not part of this group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:
df:-

```
    A   B
    1   a
    1   a
    1   b
    2   c
    3   d
```

Now using this dataFrame i want to get the following new_df:

new_df:-

```
    item  val_not_present
    1     c             #1 doesn't have values c and d(values not part of group 1)
    1     d
    2     a             #2 doesn't have values a,b and d(values not part of group 2)
    2     b
    2     d
    3     a             #3 doesn't have values a,b and c(values not part of group 3)
    3     b
    3     c
```

or an individual DataFrame for each items like:
df1:

```
    item  val_not_present
    1     c
    1     d
```

df2:-

```
    item  val_not_present
    2     a
    2     b
    2     d
```

df3:-

```
    item  val_not_present
    3     a
    3     b
    3     c
```

I want to get all the values which are not part of that group.

Comment: Yes tried. Second and third worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is using `crosstab/pivot_table` to get counts and then filter on where count is 0 and transform to dataframe:

```
m = pd.crosstab(df['A'],df['B'])
pd.DataFrame(m.where(m.eq(0)).stack().index.tolist(),columns=['A','val_not_present'])
```

---

```
   A val_not_present
0  1               c
1  1               d
2  2               a
3  2               b
4  2               d
5  3               a
6  3               b
7  3               c
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.setdiff` and `explode`:

```
values_b = df.B.unique()
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("A")["B"].unique().apply(lambda x: np.setdiff1d(values_b,x)).rename("val_not_present").explode())
```

Output:

```
val_not_present
A   
1   c
1   d
2   a
2   b
2   d
3   a
3   b
3   c
```

Comment: Getting this error:-TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: Are there missing values (NaN) somewhere in your dataframe?

Comment: Yes there are missings.

Comment: That probably explains the error. You can fill the Nan values before running my code with `df.fillna()`, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could convert B to a [categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) datatype and then compute the value counts. Categorical variables will show categories that have frequency counts of zero so you could do something like this:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].astype('category')

new_df = (
    df.groupby('A')
    .apply(lambda x: x['B'].value_counts())
    .reset_index()
    .query('B == 0')
    .drop(labels='B', axis=1)
    .rename(columns={'level_1':'val_not_present',
                     'A':'item'})
)
```